# ionic pro live deploy download not updating UI

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im working with an ionic app with Ionic Deploy.

I followed the example

```
async performManualUpdate() {
try {
  const haveUpdate = await Pro.deploy.check();

  if (haveUpdate){
    this.downloadProgress = 0;

    await Pro.deploy.download((progress) => {
      this.downloadProgress = progress;
    })
    await Pro.deploy.extract();
    await Pro.deploy.redirect();
  }
} catch (err) {
}
```

This works. However, **the progress is not updating in view, like it is not "realtime"**.
Tried to find a workaround but there's no success. Anyone can help me?

---

Here is my **[ionic info]**

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.2.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.1
npm        : 5.8.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```